# Finding general solution of a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

$y'' - y = \frac{1}{2}e^x$

To find the general solution of the above, I understand that we need both $y_{h}(x)$ and $y_{p}(x)$.
I have found $y_{h}(x)$, the homogeneous general solution to be
$y_{h}(x) = c_{1}e^x + c_{2}e^{-x}$

And in finding $y_{p}(x)$ I have subbed $y = ue^x$ where $u = u(x)$ and derived at $u'' + 2u' = \frac{1}{2}$
However, I do not know how to proceed from here, guidance will be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You have to sub in $y=cxe^x$ where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: Since $e^x$ in right hand is one of the general roots, we must take $xe^x$.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat May I know how do I know what is the general rule for finding an appropriate equation for the substitution? I can't wrap my head around when it would be $y = ce^x$ or $y = cx^2e^x$ etc.

Comment: @MyGlasses Hi there, thanks for the explanation but may I know how to identify other cases where different substitutes would have to be used? For example when we have to try $y = Ax^2 + Bx + C$ or $y = Ax + B$ etc.

Comment: @stephchia IMHO you get to know about that, simply by trial and error.

Comment: Choosing functions for obtain special solutions depends on right hand of our equation. Usually since the left side have a derivative, we choose a function one or two degree further of the right side function.

Comment: For instance $\lambda=0$ isn't the root of characteristic equation in $y''+2y'-3y=3x^3$, so you choose $y_p=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$,  
but $\lambda=0$ is the root of characteristic equation in $y''-2y=x^2+1$, so you choose $y_p=x(Ax^2+Bx+C)$.

Comment: @MyGlasses I think I get where you're coming from! I'll try more questions to familiarise myself with it. Could I just clarify one thing however, if the right hand side given is $\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}$ instead, does it mean that we would have to go with $xe^{2x}$ instead?

Comment: make for $$y_p$$ the ansatz $$y_P=e^x(Ax+B)$$

Comment: Also in case $y''+2y'-3y=e^{\lambda_0x}$, if $\lambda_0=0$ isn't the root of characteristic equation of differential equation, then we
choose $y_p=Ae^{\lambda_0x}$, but if $\lambda=0$ be the root of characteristic equation, so we choose $y_p=x(Ae^{\lambda_0x})$.

Comment: In you example, $2$ isn't the root of characteristic equation of main differential equation, then you cant choose $xe^{2x}$. We want to try if we take $xe^{2x}$ so what happen! (Let's try $y'' - y = \frac{1}{2}e^{2x}$)

Answer (score 1):

The method you are using to find $y_{p}(x)$ is called the 'method of undetermined coefficients'.

There are lots of resources describing this method, online and in text books, and the choices for the particular integral.

See for example [this](http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-2nd%20order%20ODE%20pt2.pdf), which is just one of the first I found, that describes the complication you have encountered. ( There are of course many other ways of determining a particular integral.)

Comment: Thanks for sharing that resource, I do find the complication explained on page 11 to be exactly what I am facing currently as you and several other kind souls have mentioned - that my R.H.S is a constant multiple of one of the function in $y_{h}(x)$. It also seems that this complication occurs when one of the root is 0. Thank you.